# Joomla SQL Error 0

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I receive this error on some links:

```
Error: 0 - SQL=
SELECT id FROM jos_content WHERE catid = AND alias = 'android-tutorials'
```

How do I fix this?

Can I redirect this to 404 page?

Comment: Which Joomla version do you use? What kind of link (menu? content link?) causes that? Please provide the complete link starting with 'index.php' (the domain name is of no use).

Answer (score 2):

supply a value to compare with column `catID`

```
SELECT id FROM jos_content WHERE catid =   AND alias = 'android-tutorials'
                                        ^ missing value here
```

Comment: Where I find this file ? Can you please give that file path which have this query.